# For a probability density function $f_{X}(x)$, and a new function $y = g(x)$, why is it true that $f_{Y}(y) |dy| = f_{X}(x) |dx|$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a probability density function $f_{X}(x)$, and a new one-to-one function $y = g(x)$, why is it true that $f_{Y}(y) |dy| = f_{X}(x) |dx|$? I understand this is a key step to creating the Jacobian transformation, but cannot see it geometrically/intuitively. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to think of it in terms of distribution / probabilities rather than densities. We have

$f_Y(y) = F_Y^\prime(y) = \left(\mathbb{P}\{Y<y\}\right)^\prime = \left(\mathbb{P}\{g(X)<y\}\right)^\prime = \left(\mathbb{P}\{X<g^{-1}(y)\}\right)^\prime$

Now all you need is apply the Inverse Function Theorem.

Geometrically, Jacobian $|dy/dx|$ is related to how often a random outcome of $Y$ falls into a specified segment when we are 'rolling' $X$ with known probabilities for all the segments in $\mathbb{R}$. The function $g(\bullet)$ 'stretches' all the segments (possibly) non-linearly, so the Jacobian is the instrument to keep the scale on the simple events set in $\mathbb{R}$.